# Chessbase training annotation

Tags: training, chessbase, annotation

I am using the training annotation function of ChessBase quite extensively but have now encountered a problem. I am using ChessBase 11. When I save a game with training annotation as a pgn-file and then reopen it with ChessBase, the training questions are not triggered, but there is now text of the type

> {[%tqu "How should White play?","","",Rg4,"Black has to play non-script moves such as ",10]}

What could be the reason that ChessBase does not recognize the training annotation? Any ideas how I could try to solve this problem?

Thanks and kind regards,
Florian

Comment: Can you experiment importing the pgn with the training annotation into a previously existing CB database and see what happen?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your answers. I have contacted ChessBase and they told me that training annotation is not supported in PGN files but just in their original database format cbh. So, there is nothing to be done about this problem.

Comment: You can use the [contact us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged.